# Create duplicate tags on NuSOAP

Tags: php, xml, nusoap

I'm having some troubles with NuSOAP trying to send duplicate tags. This is the code i need to send :

```
  <PartNumbers>
    <string>string1</string>
    <string>string2</string>
  </PartNumbers>
```

I'm doing the call with this code:

```
$pn[] = 'APPSP2101V2';
$pn[] = 'ME665Y/A';
$PartNumbers = array( 'PartNumbers' => array('string'  => $pn));
$result = $client->call('GetDataSheetsLastUpdate', $PartNumbers );
```

I'm sending those two PartNumbers but instead of send the two codes it's sending the last one "ME665Y/A"

Also if i try

```
$PartNumbers = array( 'PartNumbers' => array('string'  => 'APPSP2101V2', 'string' => 'ME665Y/A'));
$result = $client->call('GetDataSheetsLastUpdate', $PartNumbers );
```

Only send the last string.

How can i make an array with the same keys but different value to make the XML look like in the beggining of the question.

Thank you in advance to all

Comment: There is an issue in your code already *before* you create the XML (you solved it in your answer), just that you're aware, it's sort of a mistake you don't want to repeat too often: https://eval.in/private/a7f4353e8d15aa - it's just not possible to have the same key twice in a PHP array. Perhaps just a little oversight of yours, just saying.

Comment: Yes i see it's not possible to have duplicate keys on PHP. Also with numeric keys like in my answer works perfect. https://eval.in/private/b8d11ed81dbe4a

Comment: Exactly. I guess that is the reason why Nusoap *can* support that then. Good luck with your project there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the following code:

```
$pn[] = 'APPSP2101V2';
$pn[] = 'ME665Y/A';
$PartNumbers = array( 'PartNumbers' => array('string'  => $pn));
$result = $client->call('GetDataSheetsLastUpdate', $PartNumbers );
```

Works perfect , the problema was in the webservice.. if the P/N isn't correct only return the P/N with information on it.